# Prefix all sources with src/ in Meson

Tags: meson-build

Relative to my project root where *meson.build* is located, all of my source files are under `src/`.

Is it possible to specify these source files in meson.build in a way that wouldn't force me to prefix them all with `src/`, given that that's somewhat redundant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prefixing source files shouldn't be needed because meson provides special function: [files()](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_functions.html#files) which generates file array object that "remembers" subdirectory. For example, in the root *meson.build* you can have:

```
subdir('src')
subdir('src_more')
exe = executable('test', sources)
```

In *src/meson.build*:

```
sources = files('a1.c', 'a2.c')
```

And in *src_more/meson.build*:

```
sources += files('b1.c', 'b2.c')
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should put a `meson.build` file in `src/` and create the list there.

Comment: Even what I do that, Meson still seems to want me to specify file paths relative to the root meson.build.

Comment: That isn't how it works, you might need to post more context.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually "build" an array of files using [`foreach` statement](http://mesonbuild.com/Syntax.html#foreach-statements):

```
raw_sources = [
    'foo.cpp',
    'foomanager.cpp',
    'foofactory.cpp'
]
sources = []

foreach file : raw_sources
    full_path = join_paths('src', file)
    sources += files(full_path)
endforeach
```

And now *sources* contains files with the desired prefix.